# mini-batch size and effect in Dlib

Tags: c++, dlib

I running `dnn_semantic_segmentation_train_ex` on my Quadro P600 using CUDA on suggested VOC2012 dataset and for some reason trainer takes mini-batches only with size not greater than 2, otherwise i got "terminate called without an active exception", while even in this example standard size of mini-batch is set for 30. In result, trained network gives result drastically different from pretrained network.
Does P600's 2GB of memory is not enough to handle mini-batches bigger than 2, or there is something else what i doing wrong? Can small mini-batch size in dlib can significantly worsen training results?